# Updateing files on Amazon’s CDN

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud, amazon-s3, cdn

is there any way to update files stored on Amazon's CDN service? Seems like it won't take any update of a file we make (eg. removing the file and storing the new one with the same file name as before). Do I have to explicitly trigger an update process to remove the files from the edge servers to get the new file contents published?

Thanks for your help

Matt

Comment: You're talking about Amazon cloudfront, right?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the same name.

You're supposed to use a new name for new versions of the same file.

1. logo.png--0
2. logo.png--1
   etc...

They will cache like you have noticed. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, Amazon does have a 24 hour cache on the S3 service, so it might take some time until your new image shows up.

As far as I know, Amazon itself recommends filename versioning if you have content that updates faster than a 24 hour cycle allows.